# Environment variable to set server port in lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

How do I set the port via environment variable with lua?

Currently my setup sets `$port` through lua:

```
server {

  set_by_lua_block $port {
    return os.getenv("PORT")

  listen       $port;

  }
```

However, doing so gives me this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in "$port" of the "listen" directive in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:93
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Speculation: don't you need a closing curly brace after the `return` to balance the opening brace?

Comment: Listen doesn't accept variables. You have to generate valid config before starting nginx. Use any template tool (bash script, ansible, whatever else)

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen if you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as posted in a comment, but wasn't posted, so I'll do it to close this out.

> Listen doesn't accept variables. You have to generate valid config
>   before starting nginx. Use any template tool (bash script, ansible,
>   whatever else)
>
> — [Alexey Ten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517149/environment-variable-to-set-server-port-in-lua#comment77998351_45517149)

If you're looking for a templating engine, I recommend ERB. See my answer to a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46507188/3970701).