# How do I use nginx variables in a regex pattern while declaring `server_name`

Tags: nginx

When developing on my system, I use `server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.localhost$;` to capture the subdomain, however, in production, my reverse proxy is deployed over multiple domains and the domain name is stored in the nginx variable `$domain`.

How do I do a regex capture while doing string interpolation at the same time.

E.g. instead of `server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.localhost$`  how do I do `server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.${domain}$;`

Actual code:

```
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.localhost$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://sarahah.com; # get the joke? ;)
        proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.sarahah.com;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After jumping around and trying to read documents, I kinda gave up and created an `nginx.conf.erb` file, that I compile into `nginx.conf` with Ruby's `ERB`.

Seriously, if you're from the future and banging your head to fix this, just go with the `ERB` file. It's better than scripting dozens of bash `echo`s to get your environment variables into the `nginx.conf` and it's the best thing I did all week.

My code now looks like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.<%= ENV['DOMAIN'] %>$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://sarahah.com; # get the joke? ;)
        proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.sarahah.com;
    }
```